# 64 bit catkin/ boost issue

Tags: catkin, boost, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a new ubuntu 64 bit 14.04 upgrade and a project which used to build successfully with catkin_make.  Now I'm getting

make[2]: *** No rule to make target `/usr/lib/libboost_regex-mt.so', needed by ... < one of my source files>

I've re-installed ros/indigo

Any ideas?  (thanks in advance)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/193486/64-bit-catkin/-boost-issue/) by [blakeh](https://answers.ros.org/users/14931/blakeh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 17 on 2014-09-25

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mago Nick](https://answers.ros.org/users/5206/mago-nick/) on 2014-09-26**:
I know it may sounds obvious did you try to install the library

```
libboost-regex-dev
```

and its dependencies? Or alternatively:

```
libboost-all-dev
```

to install everything

**Comment by [blakeh](https://answers.ros.org/users/14931/blakeh/) on 2014-09-26**:
Thanks - obvious is OK!   However :  apt-get install returned:

libboost-all-dev is already the newest version.

**Comment by [Mago Nick](https://answers.ros.org/users/5206/mago-nick/) on 2014-09-27**:
@blanke, I have various ideas

1. remove build and devel and try to recompile
2. check if you are including boost libraries properly in the cmake file of your project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you just upgraded you need to make sure that all generated and itermediate files are removed before recompiling. The build system cannot track changes to system libraries, you need to force it to refind them and remove all references to the old files. Typically this involves an rm -rf of build devel and install folders. Or the isolated versions if using isolated builds.

Edit:

The missing files are installed by libboost-regex1.54-dev on my system:

```
$ dpkg -L libboost-regex1.54-dev
/.
/usr
/usr/share
/usr/share/doc
/usr/share/doc/libboost-regex1.54-dev
/usr/share/doc/libboost-regex1.54-dev/copyright
/usr/lib
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_regex.a
/usr/share/doc/libboost-regex1.54-dev/changelog.Debian.gz
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_regex.so
```

You need to make sure that cmake can find boost correctly and invalidate any cmake caches if the version or location of boost has changed. (rm -rf of build and devel are the recommended way to make sure to invalidate those caches. If you're linking against other things compiled from source you will need to rebuild/link them as well.)

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2014-09-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [blakeh](https://answers.ros.org/users/14931/blakeh/) on 2014-11-04**:
We had another upgrade pushed (by IT org) and this happened again (as you predicted!)  But, removing build and devel did not solve the problem.

**Comment by [Ruud](https://answers.ros.org/users/20263/ruud/) on 2015-03-03**:
Did anyone find a better solution yet? Same problem here!